# How to remove letters from end of ID string (variable letter amount)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of ID's that I'm trying to clean and compare with another list. The ID's have variable formatting (e.g. RFP322343BA, PPL232334, RFP32334A-00). I'm trying to standardize the data on the front-end (e.g. RFP322343, PPL232334, and RFP32234) to allow for comparison. How can I remove these end text/symbol strings of varying length?

Comment: How about just taking a substring of the first 10 characters?

Comment: The ID's are of variable length, as is the end-positioning of the letters. Meaning that many of the ID's might be below 10 characters, and keep the letter additions intact (e.g. RFP3324AB). So a consistent sample of 10 wouldn't work, I'm trying to pull off the end letters no matter where they fall or the number of them.

Comment: In that case, you are going to have to use `Regular Expressions` to solve this.  Here is a good primer on Regex in Excel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 0):

With RFP32334A-00 in cell A1, then
    =IF(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,9),1)="A",LEFT(A1,8),LEFT(A1,9))
works, assuming 1) only the first 9 chars are of interest and 2) it is only ever "A" in the 9th place for the "odd" number you provided above. If there are only a few of these odd ones, then just left(a1,9) will be simpler.

Comment: As mentioned above, sometimes it's the first 9 characters, sometimes it is fewer. I'd like the ability to remove the end letters/symbols regardless of their length/position. Would it be possible to count the number of them from the right and then remove them?

Comment: well, you could start with =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4) but you still have the same problem (that I did not see when I first looked at the original submission) of defining the number of chars to drop - notice I set it to 4 in this example.

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of at the moment is to do an edit&replace for the suffixes - but depends how many of them you have...

Comment: There are quite a few suffixes, and some contain the same letters as the prefixes. Plus, I'd like a formula to have records of the transformation.

Comment: Then it looks like you will need the information that Raj More provided the link to above about Regular Expressions, also, you could then adapt the code to keep in another cell the removed chars for the records you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function FirstPart(sIn As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, Armed As Boolean, CH As String
    FirstPart = ""
    Armed = False
    L = Len(sIn)

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            Armed = True
        End If
        If Not Armed Then
            FirstPart = FirstPart & CH
        Else
            If Not IsNumeric(CH) Then
                Exit Function
            Else
                FirstPart = FirstPart & CH
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It locates the first non-numerical character after the first numerical character and clips the string at that point.

[image]